# Order histogram plotly express legend alphabetically or according to the value presented in the y-axis

Tags: python, histogram, legend, alphabetical, plotly-express

I have a question about the legend of a histogram made through plotly express.

Is there a way to sort alphabetically or according to the value presented in the y-axis the data that appears in the legend?

Thank you so much.

I have read documentation and some similar questions in other forums, but I can't find an optimal solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think histograms are designed to be reordered, so I think reordering the calculation results in `np.histogram` to make a bar chart would suit your purpose.